# Why does Stroustrup in "The C++ Programming Language 3rd Edition (online)" define the function sqrt?

Tags: c++

Bjarne Stroustrup, in 3rd edition ([online](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/files/Bjarne_Stroustrup_-_The_C++_Programming_Language_3rd_Ed.pdf)) of his book "The C++ Programming Language" chapter 2, page 23 (pdf page 34), in a snippet paradigm, defines the function `sqrt`. Why does he not just use the one already included in the standard library?

Comment: Because it's an example?

Comment: The book was discussing concepts, and illustrating it by discussing `sqrt()` as an example of good style.    The function is not actually defined - unless you consider that a comment saying "code for calculating a square root" somehow causes the function to be magically implemented.   In C++, things simply don't happen that way.

Comment: If your bio is the truth, then I applaud you as I couldn't believe you could exist!

Comment: Mr. DeiDei, please accept my many thanks for your comment. Unfortunately my biography is absolutely true. However it is also absolutely true that I exist!  Regards.

Comment: Mr Peter, please accept my many thanks for your comment. My opinion is that code is just implied. Regards.

Comment: Mr Some programmer dude, please accept my many thanks for your coment. Unfortunately due to question mark, it is confusing me more than Mr. Stroustrup's snippet! Regards.

Comment: Messrs. Filburt, πάντα ῥεῖ, Peter, Eelke, tom redfern, please accept my many thanks for put on hold my question as primarily opinion-based, and let me say that every answer to, and comment on, any question, is primarily opinion-based. Regards.

Answer (score 7):

Because `sqrt` is an example of a *'good style'* procedural function. It takes an input, processes it, and returns the result.

The book is not suggesting that you should write you own, or to copy the definition from the book (which lacks the implementation entirely anyway). The book also isn't demonstrating how to calculate a square root. It is describing the purpose of functions in procedural programming (or that's my interpretation anyway).

Comment: Mr. user2079303, please accept my many thanks for your answer. However I think book has been written in 1997, before function sqrt() becomes standard. Unfortuneley Mr. Author retained snippet in after that editions. Regards.

Comment: @GeorgeTheodosiou 1997 is right before C++ was officially standardized yes, but I would assume that standardization was well underway and  contents of the standard library (mostly if not entirely) decided by then. `sqrt` in particular is inherited from the C standard library, which was standardized in 1989. I don't know for sure, but I have a hunch that the pre-standard UNIX C library also provided the `sqrt` function. I don't find the example unfortunate. It is a good example of a procedural function.

Answer (score 0):

And just in case you are considering writing your own sqrt(), take a look at some source code, e.g., the first that I found with Google:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-92/ppc.subproj/sqrt.c

ACCU's October 2016 Overload magazine has an article 'Eight Rooty Pieces'

https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2294

The bogosqrt() solution I found particularly amusing.

Comment: Mr. Paul Floyd, please accept my many thanks for your answer. I'm not considering writing my own sqrt() but got confused with Mr. Stroustrup's snippet paradigm, for he defines sqrt() (implying code), while this function is standard in c++. Regards.